# How to insert strings into array and let it choose between 2D arrays a random array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I can't really think of a suitable question sentence, so let me explain what am I trying to do here.

I'm running a project where the user will input sentences into my program/temporary memory. It will then scans for words, then it will pass the word ( it can be anything ) into a variable - let just call it myWord.

Simultaneously, that word will be scan through my arrays ( database ) to look for its synonyms. That synonym will then be chose randomly from my list of arrays and then be assigned to myWord. The myWord will overwrite the sentence originally input and output the new sentence.

Conclusively, how can I code to make my software scan the sentence that hold synonyms ( i will not change all words to its synonyms, just certain word - can code that myself )  and to choose its synonyms (to rewrite original) from arrays?

Any ideas, algorithms, approaches or libraries is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Is the main problem storing strings or picking something at random?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what kind of problem is that attempt facing? The way the question is written, is too broad for this website.

Comment: SO ain't a chatroom. Although it does have chatrooms. Maybe you could try there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using c++11, what you can use is an unordered map of word to all its synonyms:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

unordered_map<string, vector<string>> makeSynonyms() {
   unordered_map<string, vector<string>> synonyms;
   // load up your synonyms
   synomyms["happy"] = {"cheerful", "pleased", "delighted"};
   synomyms["cheerful"] = {"happy", "pleased", "delighted"};
   synonyms["pleased"] = {"happy", "cheerful", "delighted"};
   return synonyms;
}
```

Now to use it, you can pick a random synonym from the synonyms map for each word in your input.

```
unordered_map<string, vector<string>> synonyms = makeSynonyms();
string myWord = "happy";
vector<string> wordSynonyms = synonyms[myWord]; // this gets a list of synonyms
// now you can get a random element from the list
```